# Extract lat/lng from an Instagram photo via API

Tags: geolocation, instagram

By default, Instagram saves geo tags for all submitted photos. You can then search by location using `/media/search`. However, when I try to extract the geo tags from a specific pic using `/media/media-id`, I always get `"location": null` in the json response and no lat/lng pairs.

Is this functionality simply blocked by Instagram? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get /media/{media-id} endpoint does return location information if it is available. Users can chose not to make it available, so not every image will have it.

This example will return an image with location information. You'll need to supply your own access token:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/432039264888987277_4513750
```

The response looks something like this:

```
 {
  "meta":  {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data":  {
    "attribution": null,
    "tags":  [],
    "type": "image",
    "location":  {
      "latitude": 48.8635,
      "longitude": 2.301333333
    },
    "comments":  {
      "count": 0,
      "data":  []
    },
    ..........
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's all to it. AFAIK you can find an image in media/search according to its location attributes (which means it has it) but then when you use /media/media-id on that same image the location doesn't come up.

Comment: I haven't seen that before. Do you have an example of one of these searches I could take a look at?

Comment: My bad. I relied on earlier version of the instagram app where the lat/lng data was automatically added unless you opted out. They launched the "photo map" since and made it opt in...