# Is there a way to get latitude and longitude from an instagram post?

Tags: python, instagram

I'm trying to get information for this post: https://www.instagram.com/p/B8rgVdbA88z

I'm trying to return lat and long. There are at least 3 lat/long locations that could exist: location where photo was taken, location where photo was uploaded, location where photo is checked in (in the example link, this is "European Parliament"). It's reasonable to assume that data privacy likely blocks things like this but are any of these locations possible to return in lat/long format?

Comment: How is this relevant to Python?

Comment: Trying to use python to get this information. either requests library or instagram api or something similar

Comment: What have you found so far? With regards to an Instagram API of sorts? Posting what code you have and where you encountered problems would be very helpful.

Comment: I have found a way to return the unique media_id from the underlying url (https://www.instagram.com/p/B8rgVdbA88z/?__a=1). In this example the media_id = 2246031051363438387 but I just can't find any services available that allow for getting location from that unique info.

Comment: This isn't free coding service attended by bored people.  Show your attempt.  If you're trying to use python as you claim, then show your python code.

Comment: @j413254 is what you're asking for even possible via any public Instagram API? Have you checked?

Comment: @RandomDavis I found something close. There is an unofficial API provided by Facebook here https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram

Answer (score 1):

There is a graph api you can use. @krisrak wrote a helpful answer about that here: [Where I can find location id of location when using Instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645645/where-i-can-find-location-id-of-location-when-using-instagram-api)

It's not the exact same use case as you are trying to find locations of post ids rather than location ids but maybe there is some overlap there. I hope that's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There's also this approach but I doubt that's still available since it's been so long.

[Extract lat/lng from an Instagram photo via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945752/extract-lat-lng-from-an-instagram-photo-via-api)